# Node Promise with loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, backend

this is my problem:

I am making a request to a table in my database, with the result of that request I want to make two requests to another table, the result of these two requests want to add them to the main request (first). The problem is that the two requests were actually made, but when trying to place the result of both in the main result will not let me. the 2nd Then also runs when the first is not over (ending supposed when the first loop ends)

Maybe the error is very stupid, I'm newbie with promises.

Thanks

extract code:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var mysql = require('promise-mysql');

app.get('/misPartidos', function (req, res) {

 var query = conexion.query('SELECT partidos.id_partido, partidos.id_torneo, partidos.nlocal, partidos.nvisitante, partidos.idlocal,partidos.idvisitante, partidos.jornada, partidos.glocal, partidos.gvisitante, partidos.fecha, torneos.nombre_torneo, partidos.estado, torneos.version, torneos.modo, torneos.tipo FROM partidos INNER JOIN equipos ON(equipos.id_equipo = partidos.idlocal OR equipos.id_equipo = partidos.idvisitante) INNER JOIN participantes ON(equipos.id_equipo = participantes.id_equipo AND equipos.id_torneo = participantes.idtorneo_part) INNER JOIN torneos ON(participantes.idtorneo_part = torneos.id_torneo) WHERE participantes.username = "'+ req.query.usuario + '" ORDER BY jornada ASC')
 .then(function(success){
     for(var x in success){
         conexion.query('SELECT username,nombre_eq FROM equipos WHERE id_equipo = '+success[x].idlocal)
             .then(function(local){
                 success[x].local = local[0].username;     
         });
         conexion.query('SELECT username, nombre_eq FROM equipos WHERE id_equipo = '+success[x].idvisitante)
             .then(function(visitante){
                 success[x].visitante = visitante[0].username;
         });
         return success;
     }

 }).then(function(resultado){
     console.log(results);
 }).catch(function(error){
     console.log(error);
 });
});
```

Comment: The return on the for loop will terminate the loop after one iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `success` argument is an array of query results, you can do this:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var mysql = require('promise-mysql');

app.get('/misPartidos', function (req, res) {
    var queryString = 'SELECT partidos.id_partido, partidos.id_torneo, partidos.nlocal, partidos.nvisitante, partidos.idlocal,partidos.idvisitante, partidos.jornada, partidos.glocal, partidos.gvisitante, partidos.fecha, torneos.nombre_torneo, partidos.estado, torneos.version, torneos.modo, torneos.tipo FROM partidos INNER JOIN equipos ON(equipos.id_equipo = partidos.idlocal OR equipos.id_equipo = partidos.idvisitante) INNER JOIN participantes ON(equipos.id_equipo = participantes.id_equipo AND equipos.id_torneo = participantes.idtorneo_part) INNER JOIN torneos ON(participantes.idtorneo_part = torneos.id_torneo) WHERE participantes.username = "'+ req.query.usuario + '" ORDER BY jornada ASC';

    Promise.map(conexion.query(queryString), function(item) {
        return Promise.all([
            conexion.query('SELECT username,nombre_eq FROM equipos WHERE id_equipo = '+item.idlocal).then(function(local) {
                 item.local = local[0].username;     
            }),
            conexion.query('SELECT username, nombre_eq FROM equipos WHERE id_equipo = '+item.idvisitante).then(function(visitante){
                 item.visitante = visitante[0].username;
            })
        ]).then(function() {
            // make the return value from `Promise.all()` be the item
            // we were iterating
            return item;
        });
    }).then(function(results) {
        // array of results here
        console.log(results);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        // error here
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

This does the following:

1. Use Bluebird's `Promise.map()` to iterate through all the results from your first query
2. Uses `Promise.all()` within each iteration so that each iteration returns a single promise that represents both the sub-queries you do.
3. Return the single item as the result from each iteration
4. When all the iterations and sub-queries are done, you should end up with an array of results.

Answer (score 1):

It's ok to have troubles with promises. This is a tricky thing.

First of all, save this [great article](http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html) about promises and problems.

About your question. The problem is promises are async and for-loop is not. You need to use map-loop and return it. It will guarantee that all action will be done and only after that 2nd promise will start. There are 2 ways:

- using Promise (ES6): 
  `return Promise.all( array_of_your_elements.map( elem => {
         // some actions
         // ...
         return;
  }))`
- using async-await (ES7): `async function_name() {
   await* array_of_your_elements.map( elem => {
         // some actions
         // ...
         return;
   })
  }`

I like 2nd way more.

**IMPORTANT**: you should always use return in map. It can be empty return (as is in example) or something. If you will return, for example, string at every iteration, it will give you an array of promises with strings.

Enjoy promises!

Comment: the 2nd then dont wait for the 1st promise was resolved

Comment: Good answer, now i got this: https://gist.github.com/martinop/61cfab7f8b72b5ae9c2a